# I need help understanding the java programmer 1 practise exam answer (#1)

Tags: java

I don't fully understand why the answer is such. This is the code given on the example question:

```
public class Sequence 
{ 
    Sequence() 
    { 
      System.out.print("c "); 
    } 

    { 
      System.out.print("y "); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
      new Sequence().go(); 
    } 

    void go() 
    { 
      System.out.print("g ");
    } 

    static 
    { 
      System.out.print("x "); 
    } 
}
```

So the question is what is the output/result. And the answer is: `xycg`

Can anyone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 3):

Static block executes when class is loaded, i.e no instance of object is needed. So in your case:

```
static 
{ 
   System.out.print("x "); 
}
```

will print `x` first. It always gets executed first, when the class is loaded.

Any block that is not in the constructor (called `instance block`) will get executed before the constructor (and after the call to `super()` in case on inheritance) **but not** before any static blocks, so:

```
{ 
   System.out.print("y "); 
}
```

will then print `y`

When you create an instance of the class `Sequence`, you invoke it's constructor, so:

```
Sequence() 
{ 
   System.out.print("c "); 
}
```

will print `c`.

Finally you invoke the method `go` of an `Sequence` object:

```
void go() 
{ 
   System.out.print("g ");
}
```

which will print `g`

Because of all this, the result is: `x y c g`

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That cleared it up.